# What is the surface water to land ratio in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know the worlds are generated randomly by a seed the creation of a new world. I also know that there are rules to how everything is put together. Water only between these levels (as an ocean) ores of type X found in range Y, everything pretty much between 0 and 128.

What I am looking for is if there is also some sort of rhyme or reason to just the overall shape/makeup of land on the surface level. Like is there some sort of ratio that this % of the surface must be covered in water vs land or the like.

I hope this clears up my question as again, I know its all random at the end of the day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This depends entirely on the [random seed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Random_seed) used to generate the world.

Update: This blog post by Notch on [Terrain generation in Minecraft](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361/terrain-generation-part-1) may be of interest to you even though it doesn't give you the figures you are looking for. Basically: The terrain is generated from [Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) with some manipulations to ensure that there is *enough* land and water. This means the ratio will fall within some range (but I can't say what it is, sorry).

Comment: This can still be answered generically by giving the average case.

Comment: Only if the distribution is normal.

Comment: We need someone to hack up a quick program that generates many thousands of maps and run some stats.

Comment: @Zoredache Only on a Stack Exchange website would a community elect to do something like this. :)

Comment: @Rein: There are lots of distributions other than the normal distribution where the mean is of interest.

Comment: @Tim true, but we're talking about a PRNG. Most of those distributions (Poisson, Erlang, etc) are irrelevant.

Comment: @Rein: It would indeed be pointless to find the average of the results of the PRNG since it has a uniform distribution. What this question concerns is the distribution of water-to-land ratio (within some radius) over different seeds, and it is plausible that it approximates a distribution that is a lot nicer.

Comment: @Tim From what I understand, Notch uses Perlin noise to generate the terrain, with some manipulation to ensure that there is *enough* land and water. What I don't know (and can't speculate on) is if this just trims the ends of the distribution off or shapes the distribution into something more normal.

Comment: @Rein: Ok, I didn't know about that. Then I suppose it is possible to answer this question in a more meaningful way, although you are right in that it completely depends on the seed.

Comment: @Tim I suppose it would be possible for Notch or someone who has generated a statistically significant sample ;)

Comment: @zoredache You could probably increase the generation speed by several factors if you skipped generating the maps entirely, and simply calculated the biome areas in different seeds, then just checked ocean biome vs not to get a very rough ratio of water vs land.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a land\water ratio per 9 square chunks or anything, because my friend (he also plays MineCraft) spawned in a forest biome and even when he tried walking in one direction for 5 MineCraft days however he couldn't find a large body of water anywhere, only small lakes, so unless his world has *heaps* of underground lakes, there isn't much of a rule to land/water amounts.

Answer (score -1):

It definitely depends on what seed you are in, but I'm sure there is an average amount. I would guess the average is between 25 and 60 percent, but I have no idea.